# c3p0 "getConnection" is slow

Tags: java, applet, c3p0

I'm using c3p0 connection pool for communication between my (unsigned) Java applet and MySql db.
I have this code for initializing pool:

```
DataSource pool = pools.get(db_name);
if(pool == null) 
    pool = initializePool(db_name);
return pool.getConnection();
```

Initialize pool method looks like this:

```
protected DataSource initializePool(String db_name) throws SQLException {
    try {
        ComboPooledDataSource cpds = new ComboPooledDataSource();
        cpds.setDriverClass("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        cpds.setJdbcUrl(connectionDetails.getConnectionString(db_name));
        cpds.setUser(connectionDetails.getUsername()); 
        cpds.setPassword(connectionDetails.getPassword());
        pools.put(db_name, cpds);
        return cpds;
    } catch (PropertyVetoException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new SQLException("JDBC driver could not be initialized propertly");   
    }
}
```

My c3p0-config.xml is simple:

```
<c3p0-config><default-config>
<property name="acquireIncrement">1</property>
<property name="initialPoolSize">5</property>
<property name="minPoolSize">1</property>
<property name="maxPoolSize">7</property>
<property name="maxConnectionAge">0</property>
<property name="maxIdleTime">600</property>
<property name="maxIdleTimeExcessConnections">120</property> 
<property name="automaticTestTable">C3p0_test_table</property>
<property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod">60</property>
<property name="testConnectionOnCheckin">true</property></default-config></c3p0-config>
```

The problem is that "getConnection" call takes sometimes even 10 or more seconds to respond when i call a database for the first time (second time i contact a db it's faster). I've been looking all over the net and "c3p0" manual for way to speedup connection pool without luck.

When i run my applet (from server) java console output looks like this:

```
Jan 16, 2013 12:57:14 PM com.mchange.v2.log.MLog <clinit>
INFO: MLog clients using java 1.4+ standard logging.
Jan 16, 2013 12:57:16 PM com.mchange.v2.c3p0.C3P0Registry <clinit>
INFO: jdk1.5 management interfaces unavailable... JMX support disabled.
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("javax.management.MBeanServerPermission" "createMBeanServer")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer(Unknown Source)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.management.ActiveManagementCoordinator.<init>(ActiveManagementCoordinator.java:42)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.C3P0Registry.<clinit>(C3P0Registry.java:134)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.PoolBackedDataSourceBase.<init>(PoolBackedDataSourceBase.java:228)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.<init>(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:62)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource.<init>(ComboPooledDataSource.java:109)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource.<init>(ComboPooledDataSource.java:105)
    ...

Jan 16, 2013 12:57:16 PM com.mchange.v2.c3p0.C3P0Registry banner
INFO: Initializing c3p0-0.9.1.2 [built 21-May-2007 15:05:05; debug? true; trace: 10]
Jan 16, 2013 12:57:16 PM com.mchange.v2.c3p0.PoolConfig <clinit>
WARNING: Read of system Properties blocked -- ignoring any c3p0 configuration via System properties! (But any configuration via a c3p0.properties file is still okay!)
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "*" "read,write")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPropertiesAccess(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.getProperties(Unknown Source)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.PoolConfig.<clinit>(PoolConfig.java:101)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0ImplUtils.defaultConnectionTester(C3P0ImplUtils.java:283)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.<init>(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:47)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.<init>(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:67)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource.<init>(ComboPooledDataSource.java:114)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource.<init>(ComboPooledDataSource.java:105)
    ...

started taking connection - Wed Jan 16 12:57:16 CET 2013
Jan 16, 2013 12:57:20 PM com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource getPoolManager
INFO: Initializing c3p0 pool... com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource [ some connection info and params for DB1]
Connection taken - Wed Jan 16 12:57:23 CET 2013
started taking connection - Wed Jan 16 12:57:23 CET 2013
Jan 16, 2013 12:57:24 PM com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource getPoolManager
INFO: Initializing c3p0 pool... com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource [ some connection info and params for DB2]
Connection taken - Wed Jan 16 12:57:24 CET 2013
```

What am i missing? Is there a way to speed up process of getting connection? I thought that it might be a server issue, but i'm having those lags even when i run my applet from eclipse (and make it contact remote database at server). Please help, or at least explain me why getting connection is so slow?

Comment: How long does it takes to connect to the remote database using some other tool, like the mysql command line client? Are you sure it's not just network latency, or that the DNS resolution is taking too long? Does the same lag happens every time you start the applet, or if you quit the applet and start it again it's faster?

Comment: Well, it's faster when i start it from localhost and it connects to remote db. Strangely problem is when applet and db are both on the server and i'm testing applet from my computer. It runs a bit faster when i close the applet and start it again, but not much. Command-line mysql is fast.

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely it's testConnectionOnCheckin=true that's killing you.  Since c3p0 offloads this work to background threads - these operations appear to back up and the connections are not immediately available to be re-used.